# Thread sleeping works differently than expected

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to Java and would like to know where I'm going wrong with this code

```
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        textArea.setText("\n***Iterate***\n");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }
```

what I expect for this to do is for every iteration, it should have an interval of a second. But what happens is that when it runs, it sleeps for 10 seconds, and then the for loop runs as how it would without the thread.sleep().

Comment: I don't think so. I suppose that the textArea simply buffers your setText calls. I don't know what is the textArea in your case, but I suppose it's a part of some kind of GUI framework. In that case, bet your framework has some kind of implementation of "Timers". Please consider of using Timers rather than sleep.

Comment: Depends on what a `textArea` is, if you're repainting, etc. E.g., if you do this w/ a println if you don't flush it might not show up until it's all done.

Comment: If you're doing this on the EDT, it stops updating because you're blocking the EDT>

Comment: Will look into Timers. Thank you @Vicctor

Answer (score 1):

If this is being done on the EDT (which you should because you're updating a Swing component), then it's because you're blocking the EDT for 10 seconds.

Consider a Swing timer instead.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

```
class MyActionListener implements ActionListner {
  Timer mytimer;
  int count;
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    textArea.setText("\n***Iterate***\n");
    if( ++count > 10 ) mytimer.stop();
  }
};

MyActionListener task = new MyActionListener();
Timer timer = new Timer(1000, task )
task.mytimer = timer;
timer.setRepeats( true );
timer.start();
```

Code is untested.